# Nested each loops in jQuery templates

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I am using Knockout and JQuery.tmpl libraries. My template works incorrect. Here it is:

```
<script type="text/html" id="filters">
    {{each(i1, item1) addedFilters}}
    <div>
        <select>
            {{each(i2, item2) filters}}
            <option value='${SystemFieldName}'
            {{if $item1 == $item2}}selected{{/if}}>
                ${Field}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Value" />
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

The problem is in IF statement. It says: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $item1 is not defined.`

Why?

(Without if statement it works as it should be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct if statement should look like that:

`{{if item1 == item2}}selected{{/if}}` - without dollar sign